# How to add date on x-axis in g.raphael line chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I am using Raphael line chart ..But how i display date on x-axis.

I tried below code.

window.onload = function () {

```
            var r = Raphael("holder"),
                txtattr = { font: "12px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif" };
```

var lines = r.linechart(330, 250, 300, 220, [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,10]], [[17, 32, 23, 15, 17, 11,13]],

{

nostroke: false, axis: "0 0 1 1", symbol: "circle", smooth: true }).hoverColumn(function () {

```
                this.tags = r.set();

                for (var i = 0, ii = this.y.length; i < ii; i++) {
                    this.tags.push(r.tag(this.x, this.y[i], this.values[i], 160, 10).insertBefore(this).attr([{ fill: "#fff" }, { fill: this.symbols[i].attr("fill") }]));
                }
            }, function () {
                this.tags && this.tags.remove();
            });

            lines.symbols.attr({ r: 6 });
```

};

By using above code its displaying number on x-axis..
But how to display date on X-axis.